# Não consigo inicializar o Tomcat no Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

Quando iniciei o Tomcat no Netbeans deu o seguinte erro:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\chrissian\Desktop\Todo sobre o JAVA\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.63"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\chrissian\Desktop\Todo sobre o JAVA\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.63"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\chrissian\Desktop\Todo sobre o JAVA\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\chrissian\Desktop\Todo sobre o JAVA\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\chrissian\Desktop\Todo sobre o JAVA\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
jul 29, 2015 9:14:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
GRAVE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

jul 29, 2015 9:14:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
ADVERTÊNCIA: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (21, 76) : org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
jul 29, 2015 9:14:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
GRAVE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:679)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

jul 29, 2015 9:14:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
ADVERTÊNCIA: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (21, 76) : org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
jul 29, 2015 9:14:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você já conseguiu fazer ele funcionar alguma vez antes?

Comment: você tem outra versão do tom cat no netbeans? se tiver apaga uma delas e deixa o catalina_home apontando somente para o atual

Comment: Tente executar o Netbeans como administrador da máquina, Esses costumam ocorrer no Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Observe que a exceção é do tipo ClassNotFoundException.
Ou seja, a classe não foi encontrada.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
```

Certifique-se de que todos as bibliotecas necessárias (**.jar**), estão dentro do diretório WEB-INF/lib